# SELECT data with multiple rows using the same id based on 3 columns

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a table Data which contains some data. Several rows belong to the same customer having the same customer_id (index to Customers table). This customer has answered some questions which they have question_id (index to Questions table). In the Data table, there is also the value column regarding the answer of the customer to question0

[image: Data Table]

I am trying to select the customer_id for which the answers to question_id 1, 2, 3 are 0

I have also tried

```
SELECT distinct customer_id
FROM Data
WHERE value = 0
AND question_id IN (1, 2, 3);
```

but I am not getting the appropriate result which should be **24** which is the customer_id of the customer that has answered 0 to the questions with question_id 1, 2 and 3.

Comment: Specify the expected result as well. (Having the above table data.) BTW, most people here want formatted text, not images.

Comment: Both answers given by the Wanderer and Gordon Linoff are correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are close.  You can get what you want using `group by` and `having`:

```
SELECT customer_id
FROM Data
WHERE value = 0 AND question_id IN (1, 2, 3)
GROUP BY customer_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT question_id) = 3;
```

The `HAVING` clause specifies that all three questions are answered -- and that the answers are `0`.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way with **`GROUP BY`** and **`HAVING`**.

**Query**

```
select `customer_id`
from `your_table_name`
where `question_id` in (1,2,3)
group by `customer_id`
having sum(`value`) = 0;
```

**[Find a demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5a5344/1)**